# "Virtual" and Header Files

Tags: c++, header, virtual

I have Foo.hpp and Foo.cpp, i'd like to define a virtual function

```
virtual void setValue(int val){
}
```

Would the following implementation be correct:

**Foo.hpp**

```
#ifndef _FOO
#define _FOO
class Foo{
  public:
    Foo();
    virtual void setValue(int val);
};
#endif
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
Foo::setValue(){

}
```

I realise it would be easier if i kept it to one file, but this is just a simplification of a more complex structure.

Comment: Is this intended to be a base class for another type?  Ie, there is a bar that inherits from foo?

Comment: Yes that's what attempting to do eventually.

Comment: If your confused about getting syntax correct, I'd recommend getting one of the books that Kline mentions for legal syntax: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/how-to-learn-cpp.html#faq-28.6  I tried to work without one of these books, asking questions on SO on syntax and stuff, and found that the book answered the question better than anyone on here could, and saved me a lot of time.  Just a bit of advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example won't compile, because the function signatures are different between your cpp and hpp, but you have the right idea.  If your function is void, there is no need to return, either.